# Check if element has transition set in CSS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have a transition set:

```
element.one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ 
    scrollActive = false;
}).css({
    '-webkit-transform': '' + prop + '(' + value + 'px)',
    '-ms-transform': '' + prop + '(' + value + 'px)',
    'transform': '' + prop + '(' + value + 'px)'
});
```

and in CSS:

```
.element {
    transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

If I don't have transition set in CSS, the `transitionend` event will never fire.

Is there a way to check if element has transition set?

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(element);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `getComputedStyle().getPropertyValue()` here. The default value of transition is `all 0s ease 0s`, if not applied in an element

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".element");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("transition");
if (style === "all 0s ease 0s") {
  console.log("Not set");
} else {
  console.log("Set");
}
```

```css
.element {
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Window.getComputedStyle()

```
 const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

 const hasTransition = styles.transition !== "all 0s ease 0s";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

**WARNING**: This function is very expensive to calculate.